# @Autowired based on a property inside application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, kotlin, autowired

Suppose I have several Spring components implementing a single interface:

```
interface Haha
@Component class HahaImpl1: Haha {
   @Autowired lateinit var repo: JpaRepository<Data, Long>
}
@Component class HahaImpl2: Haha

@Service
class Yoyo {
   @Autowired lateinit var haha: Haha
}
```

How can inject the correct dependency into my `Yoyo` service, which I could specify inside the `application.properties` file?

```
myApp.haha=impl1
```

I could create a configuration, but then I would have to remove the `@Component` annotation, which I would not want, since inside the Haha implementation classes I would inject other beans (services, controllers, etc):

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["myApp.haha"], havingValue = "impl1", matchIfMissing = true)
    fun config1(): Haha = HahaImpl1()

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["myApp.haha"], havingValue = "impl2")
    fun config2(): Haha = HahaImpl2()
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *which I would not want, since inside the Haha implementation classes I would inject other beans*: you don't need a Component annotation to have that. You just need the object to be a Spring bean, which it is, since you return it from a `@Bean`-annotated method.

Comment: @JBNizet you mean that during bean instantiation (let's say ``config1()``) Spring will look inside the ``HahaImpl1`` class and autowire all its dependencies (``repo: JpaRepository<Data, Long>``)?

Comment: Yes, except that will of course happen *after* the bean instantiation. Not during it.

Comment: @JBNizet I was confused, since Intellij 2017.3 throws a highlight warning on the haha property: ``coudn't autowire: there's more than one bean of 'Haha' type``.  And inside ``HahaImpl1`` @Autowired is warned with ``Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring beans``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could solve the problem by moving the `@ConditionalOnProperty` to your bean classes and deleting the `@Configuration` class entirely (or at least remove the parts that deal with `HaHa` instances):

```
interface HaHa

@Component 
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myApp.haha", havingValue = "impl1", matchIfMissing = true)
class HahaImpl1: Haha {
    @Autowired 
    lateinit var repo: JpaRepository<Data, Long>
}

@Component 
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myApp.haha", havingValue = "impl2")
class HahaImpl2: Haha {
    // ...
}
```

This way you always get one instance of `HaHa`, and only based on the presence of absence of properties. This works because `@ConditionalOnProperty` can appear on a [Method or a Type](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the `@Component` annotation from all Haha implementation classes.

```
interface Haha
class HahaImpl1: Haha {
    @Autowired lateinit var repo: JpaRepository<Data, Long>
}
class HahaImpl2: Haha

@Service
class Yoyo {
    @Autowired lateinit var haha: Haha
}

@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["myApp.haha"], havingValue = "impl1", matchIfMissing = true)
    fun config1(): Haha = HahaImpl1()

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["myApp.haha"], havingValue = "impl2")
    fun config2(): Haha = HahaImpl2()
}
```

`application.properties` :

```
myApp.haha=impl1
#myApp.haha=impl2
```